# Regex Match between brackets (...)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to grab 2 items from a simple line.

```
[Title](Description)
```

EDIT: actually a url looking to display  called it description because i want it displayed not actually parsed.

```
[Trivium](https://www.youtube.com/user/trivium)
```

Grabbing between the brackets (...) doesn't seem to work at all for me.  I've googled and found several variations with no luck,  Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

Tried the following:

```
[(.+?)]\((.*)\)
[(.+?)]\([^\(\r\n]*\)
[(.+?)]((.+?))
```

and a cpl more I cant find again

Comment: Please show us what you've tried up to this point.

Comment: Did you remember to escape each bracket?

Comment: I am not smart with this and dont know what escape means sorry trying to learn still

Comment: It might help if you also let us know what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 11):

The first regex you listed *almost* has it right.  Try using this regex instead:

```
\[.+?\]\((.*)\)
```

As @PM 77-1 pointed out, you need to *escape* the brackets by placing a backslash in front of them.  The reason for this is that brackets are special regex metacharacters, or characters which have a special meaning.  Brackets tell the regex engine to look for classes of characters contained inside of it.

Your original regex `[(.+?)]\((.*)\)` is actually doing this:

```
[(.+?)]   match a period '.' 1 or more times
\((.*)\)  match (anything), i.e. anything contained in parentheses
```

So this regex would match `.....(stuff)` but would *not* match `[Title](Description)`, the latter which is what you really want.

Here is a link where you can test out the working regex:

[**Regex 101**](https://regex101.com/r/vK4pN8/2)

Comment: Bare with me im testing and it seems like its grabbing all the info after the bracket closes as well

Comment: `\[.+?\]\((.*)\)` Try using this regex if you just want to extract what is in between the parentheses.  Do you want to extract just the word `Description` from the example `[Title](Description)` ?

Comment: No its not actually the word description.  Its a url that i want displayed begins with http:// if that helps any

Comment: Update your OP with the URL you are trying to match, and I'll adjust my answer.  For future reference, give us the full text you are trying to match in the beginning, don't hold it for later.