# Extract text in Google Sheets in a []

Tags: string, google-sheets, extract

I'm trying to extract some text in a [] the data looks like this:
[image]

Basically I need the middle information, what I've tried was using `split` but I don't need more columns and also tried to use `=REGEXEXTRACT()` but did't work well some formulas suggestion please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex Match between brackets (...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405049/regex-match-between-brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex `\[(.+?)\]` will capture text between `[` and `]`

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2; "\[(.+?)\]")
```